# Find fields from counted rows

Tags: c#, sql, arrays

Actually I have a sql table for booking Vehicles. I book a vehicle from a form where I need to select Time_From and Time_To.

I need to put a clause here :- If there is already a booking for a Vehicle on the same date then you can't book that Vehicle between the time period, out of the time period you can book.

see my booking information below

[image]

u2ogq - Click for Next Image...

I don't know that how many times a vehicle is booked for a particular date. How can I check the all vehicle booking for a Unique vehicle for a Unique date. I need to check booking time period. I need to count the rows for particular vehicle for a particular date.

please give me hint how to put logic here on the vehicle booing form.

Thank

Comment: Please give an example what do you want achive.

Comment: If a vehicle is booked from 10:00 AM to 12:00PM and same is booked from 2:00PM to 3:00PM, then it couldn't be booked between 10:00 AM to 12:00PM  and 2:00PM to 3:00PM but yes is is available between 12:00PM to 2:00Pm for booking and after 3:00PM also available for booking.

Comment: We are close. Correct me if I am wrong. For given car and date you want to check if the car is available or for given car you want to get periods where car is not booked?

Comment: yes exactly  Wawrzyniec Sz.

Comment: yes exactly for which part?

Comment: for this--- "We are close. Correct me if I am wrong. For given car and date you want to check if the car is available or for given car you want to get periods where car is not booked? "

Answer (score 0):

Ok Well you need to create a query which returns the bookings for that period for that vehicle, this is know as a sub query. In a sub query you can pass values from the columns in the "base" query to the sub query. The sub query takes the row by row values and uses them as parameters to filter its results http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html gives (for me) one of the best set of clear examples on using subqueries (yup it was originally written for access - but MS-SQL is no different) Its very useful to get you head around these because ther are quite a feew circumstances where they are very useful. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments you are intrested with two cases:

Case 1. For given car and date you want to check if the car is available

```
    DECLARE @car VARCHAR(20) 
    DECLARE @From DATETIME
    DECLARE @To DATETIME

    SET @car = 'your car'
    SET @From = ..
    SET @To = ..

    SELECT CASE
        WHEN (
            SELECT COUNT(1) FROM booking 
                WHERE vehilce = @car
                AND (@From >= vehilce.From AND @From <= vehilce.To)
                OR (@T0 >= vehilce.From AND @T0 <= vehilce.To)
            ) >= 1 THEN "not available" 
        ELSE "available" 
        END
```

Case 2. For given car you want to get periods where car is not booked

```
SELECT vehicle , previousTo ,nextFrom FROM
            (
                SELECT t1.vehicle AS vehicle, t1.From AS previosFrom, t1.To AS previousTo , t2.From AS nextFrom, t2.To AS nextTo 
                FROM booking t1
                JOIN booking t2 ON t1.vehicle,t2.vehicle OR t1.To < t2.From
                WHERE vehicle= @car
                GROUP BY vehicle, previosFrom, previousTo
                HAVING nextFrom = MIN (nextFrom)
            ) a
```